# How to select a particular type and exclude others in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, ssms-2012

Was just wondering if it's possible to select rows which uses only particular type and not anything else in SSMS.

**For example:**

```
╔════════╦══════╗
║ UserID ║ Type ║
╠════════╬══════╣
║      1 ║ A    ║
║      1 ║ B    ║
║      1 ║ C    ║
║      1 ║ D    ║
║      2 ║ D    ║
║      3 ║ A    ║
║      3 ║ C    ║
║      3 ║ D    ║
║      4 ║ B    ║
║      4 ║ C    ║
║      5 ║ C    ║
║      5 ║ D    ║
╚════════╩══════╝
```

Now, I'm looking to find users who has only D in their profile and nothing else. For the above example, UserID 2 would be result of the query.

Comment: Yes, it is possible - does that answer your question? :) What have you tried so far?

Comment: I believe @Arvo want you to solve the problem by yourself since the answer is so simple.

Comment: I'm not not so good at SQL. That's the reason I've come here for help who are good at it. I did try solving my query with no success. I had tried a similar query as is suggested in the answer suggested below.

Answer (score 0):

You have a very poor data structure and you should focus on fixing it.  Storing values in delimited lists is a very bad idea, and not a good use of relational databases.  Instead, you want a `UserTypes` table with one row per user and one row per type.

But, sometimes we are stuck with other people's bad design choices.  In such a case, the answer to your particular question is simple:

```
select t.*
from t
where Type = 'D';
```

EDIT:

For the improved data structure:

```
select userId
from t
group by userId
having min(type) = 'D' and max(type) = 'D';
```

Comment: I had tried a similar query for my question. But it brings back all the users with Type = 'D'. I'm looking to identify userids with only 'D'

Comment: @Raja . . . This should bring back only users that have an exact "D" in the `Type` field.  You should edit your question with the query you are using.

Comment: @Gordon..I've edited my example now. I suppose giving the type as comma separated value did not serve purpose for my question. Now if we apply the query you suggested, it would bring back userids 1, 2, 3 and 5. But, I'm looking for only userid 2 to be returned as it does not have any other type associated. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    UserID
FROM
    [Table] 
GROUP BY 
    UserID HAVING COUNT(UserID)=1 and Type='D'
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Gordon suggested your's is a very poor database design an try to fix it. Below query would do your work anyways -

```
CREATE TABLE #UserIDType( UserID int,   Type char(1))
insert into #UserIDType
select 1  ,      'A' union all
select 1 ,       'B' union all
select 1 ,       'C' union all
select 1,        'D' union all
select 2,        'D' union all
select 3,        'A' union all
select 3,        'C' union all
select 3,        'D' union all
select 4,        'B' union all
select 4,        'C' union all
select 5,        'C' union all
select 5,        'D'
select userid,type from
(select *,row_number() over(partition by userid order by userid) rn 
from #useridtype) a 
where type='D' and rn=1
```

Comment: What if there is a record `2, 'E'`?

Comment: In that case I would try this query -
`select userid from
(select userid,count(rn) cnt from
(select *,row_number() over(partition by userid order by userid) rn 
from #useridtype) a
--where type='D'
group by userid) b
where cnt = 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.*
FROM YourTable T1
LEFT JOIN YourTable T2 ON T1.UserID = T2.UserID AND T2.Type <> 'D'
WHERE T1.Type = 'D' AND T2.UserID IS NULL
```

Explanation:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Type = 'D'
```

Will select all records with Type = 'D'.

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table T1
LEFT JOIN Table T2 ON T1.UserID = T2.UserID AND T2.Type <> 'D'
```

Will select all records which have type beside 'D'

Adding `WHERE T2.UserID IS NULL` selects records which don't have any other type except 'D'.

Combining these two result sets gets final result.